# Unable to merge two shapefiles (created from text files) using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, merge, error-000732

I am trying to merge two shapefiles together created from two text files.

I am new to Python and managed to get the text files into shapefiles, however, when trying to merge the two newly created shapefiles together I always get an error of some sort.

I have attached my code below:

```
import os, arcpy, shutil

if os.path.exists(r'E://tmp//ProcData'):
    shutil.rmtree(r'E://tmp//ProcData')
if not os.path.exists(r'E://tmp//ProcData'):
    os.makedirs(r'E://tmp//ProcData')

from arcpy import env
env.workspace = r'E://tmp//RawData'

importFiles = r'E://tmp//RawData'

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

for data in arcpy.ListFiles('*.txt'):
    featureClass = data.split('.')
    outputName = featureClass[0]  + '.shp'  
    outputFolder = r'E://tmp//ProcData'
    spatialRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(26917)
    textFiles = open(os.path.join(importFiles,data), 'r')
    textFiles.readline()
    files = textFiles.readlines()

    createFeatureclass = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outputFolder,outputName, 'POINT', '', '', '')

    arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'FarmID', 'TEXT')
    arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'Name', 'TEXT')
    arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'FarmType', 'TEXT')
    arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'EastingM', 'DOUBLE')
    arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'NorthingM', 'DOUBLE')
    arcpy.env.workspace = r'E://tmp//ProcData'
    shapefileList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses('*.shp')
    mergedShapefile = 'npFarm.shp'
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management('npFarm.shp', 'newLayer')
    arcpy.Merge_management(shapefileList, mergedShapefile)

    cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(createFeatureclass)   
    point.rstrip('\n')
    segmentedPoint = point.split('\t')
    idValue = segmentedPoint[0]
    nameValue = segmentedPoint[1]
    typeValue = segmentedPoint[2]
    latValue = float(segmentedPoint[3])
    longValue = float(segmentedPoint[4])

    vertex = arcpy.CreateObject('Point')
    vertex.X = latValue
    vertex.Y = longValue

    feature = cursor.newRow()      
    feature.shape = vertex
    feature.setValue('FarmID', idValue)
    feature.setValue('Name', nameValue)
    feature.setValue('FarmType', typeValue)
    feature.setValue('EastingM', latValue)
    feature.setValue('NorthingM', longValue)
    cursor.insertRow(feature)

del cursor
```

I get the following errors:

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset npFarm.shp does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (MakeFeatureLayer).
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Your description of "an error of some sort" is not very helpful.  Would you be able to use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with the precise error message that you see when you run the code you posted, please?  At a glance I would say that you would be better to pursue Merge or Append rather than using an insert cursor to try and accomplish this.

Comment: Depending on which method I use (to try and merge) I get: output folder the same, invalid parameters, cannot create folder". What happens is that it creates one of the two shapefiles and doesn't merge either.

Comment: You're creating the shapefile on each iteration, take that out of the loop and it should be fine. Consider the arcpy.da cursor (much better).

Comment: I tried taking both methods out of the loop, still got errors.

Comment: The text files have the same format? What errors? It's nice to see the actual error message, it contains important information.

Comment: I'll copy the error messages. See next comment

Comment: Trying to debug more than one method within a question makes it a moving target so can you please choose the one you want to work on and then **edit** your question to include the precise error message when the code presented is run, please?

Comment: Code edited and error attached below code!

Comment: The text files have the exact same format, Michael.

Comment: It's really hard to see what the merge has to do with anything, it doesn't match the rest of the code. What do you want to get out of this script? At first it looks like taking rows and making points then (for no apparent reason) you've got a merge in there... are you trying to turn all these text files to points then merge to an output file?

Comment: What I am trying to do is convert two text files into 2 point shapefiles, and then merge those two point shapefiles into one shapefile called "npFarm.shp". Like I said, I am brand new to Python, so I don't exactly know what I am doing.

Comment: The asker deleted their question and account, presumably thinking that was appropriate, and being unaware of how this site works.  I've rolled the question back so as not to leave the answer stranded.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import os, arcpy, shutil
from arcpy import env

if os.path.exists(r'E://tmp//ProcData'):
    shutil.rmtree(r'E://tmp//ProcData')
if not os.path.exists(r'E://tmp//ProcData'):
    os.makedirs(r'E://tmp//ProcData')

importFiles = r'E://tmp//RawData'
outputFolder = r'E://tmp//ProcData'
spatialRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(26917)

env.workspace = importFiles
env.overwriteOutput = True
AllShapeFiles = list() # empty list for now

for data in arcpy.ListFiles('*.txt'):
    featureClass = data.split('.') 
    outputName = featureClass[0]  + '.shp'  
    textFiles = open(os.path.join(importFiles,data), 'r')
    textFiles.readline()          #read the header line I presume
    files = textFiles.readlines() #reading rest of file into variable
    createFeatureclass = outputFolder + "\\" + outputName


    if not arcpy.Exists(outputFolder + "\\" + outputName):
        # create on the first iteration. This tool has no output!
        arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outputFolder,outputName, 'POINT', spatial_reference = spatialRef)

        arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'FarmID', 'TEXT')
        arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'Name', 'TEXT')
        arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'FarmType', 'TEXT')
        arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'EastingM', 'DOUBLE')
        arcpy.AddField_management(createFeatureclass, 'NorthingM', 'DOUBLE')
        AllShapeFiles.append(outputFolder + "\\" + outputName) # add to list on creation

    cursor = arcpy.InsertCursor(createFeatureclass,spatialRef)
    feature = cursor.newRow()      
    # I think this is what you're trying to do
    # you've read the data from the file into files
    # now you want to go through each line and create
    # a point for each line
    for point in files:
        point.rstrip('\n') 
        segmentedPoint = point.split('\t')
        idValue = segmentedPoint[0]
        nameValue = segmentedPoint[1]
        typeValue = segmentedPoint[2]
        latValue = float(segmentedPoint[3])
        longValue = float(segmentedPoint[4])

        vertex = arcpy.CreateObject('Point')
        vertex.X = latValue
        vertex.Y = longValue

        feature.shape = vertex
        feature.setValue('FarmID', idValue)
        feature.setValue('Name', nameValue)
        feature.setValue('FarmType', typeValue)
        feature.setValue('EastingM', latValue)
        feature.setValue('NorthingM', longValue)
        cursor.insertRow(feature)
    # remove locks on the feature class
    del feature
    del cursor

arcpy.Merge_management(AllShapeFiles,outputFolder + "\\npFarm.shp" )
```

Like PolyGeo said there were a few problems with the script so I wont go through each one individually. It was a good attempt though.

Comment: I don't think Python will like `r'E://tmp//ProcData'` so I think the asker should change that to `r'E:\tmp\ProcData'`, `'E://tmp//ProcData'` or `'E:\\tmp\\ProcData'` - I agree that there seem to be several issues with this script - to disentangle them I think they are best worked through as one code snippet per question (see [Tour]).

Comment: So I just copied that script into python, and I got the following error:

    NameError: name 'createFeatureclass' is not defined
>>>

Comment: Now the error: 

    NameError: name 'AllShapeFiles' is not defined ... easy fix though.

Comment: YES! It worked, thank you so very much for the help, I truly appreciate it.

Comment: Doh! Fat fingers! python is a case sensitive language, AllShapefiles is not the same as AllShapeFiles. I have corrected that on the first instance (AllShapeFiles = list())

Comment: I've locked this to prevent deletion of its contents by other than its author.